# Concern over bcrypt and other hash based algorithms

Tags: bcrypt

I have to store password in an encrypted form in my text file based database to make the system secure.

I am looking for possible solutions. I explored hash based algorithms such as MD5 and bcrypt. Found that bcrypt is recommended over MD5. I have a concern over the approach in these algorithms:

I still see the presence of salt with the hash a matter of concern. Moreover the algorithms make the position of salt in the hashed string public. So according to that format we have :

**$bcryptid$log_rounds$128-bit-Salt184-bit-Hash**

What if the hacker wants to break one of the accounts. He/She can read the SALT for that account, run bcrypt encryption function on that with the password attempts and compare with the string HASHED in database.

please treat the following as pseudocode:

```
for password_attempt in LIST_OF_POSSIBLE_PASSWORDS
 if (hashpw(password_attempt, SALT ) == HASHED)
  print "Hacker wins! I guessed a password!", password_attempt
```

I see that bcrypt would just make hashpw slow but i dont see the use of salt when its known for sure as plaintext in the hashed string in the database. The api should mangle the SALT in HASHED so that its not readable to the hacker. I guess its not doing so or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sufficiently good *random* hash, the attacker has to bruteforce, which is inefficient and could take longer than the lifetime of the universe to break.

If you don't use a randomely generated hash, it drastically decreases the time to crack. There is also [rainbow tables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)
That don't use salt. If you have salt, you can't use precomputed hashes.

Comment: Please refer my question, its specific to bcrypt and similar hash algorithms and the problem with their approach that i see and have cited there. Specifically whats the use of salt in bcrypt and similar algos, when its readable as clear text in the output hash string?